# Android - how do i animate a shape?

Tags: java, android, animation, physics

I need a little start-up aid. I want to animate a circle, that is 'flying' vertically, when the user swipes crabwise. What do i have to do, after creating a circle on a canvas?

```
Bitmap bg = Bitmap.createBitmap(480, 800, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 
Canvas canvas = new Canvas (bg);
canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()/2, (float) (canvas.getHeight()/1.8), 13, paint);
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://cogitolearning.co.uk/?p=877) tutorial.

Comment: Is it possible in case my shape isn't an imageView?

Comment: For beginning easiest  way - use Android Animation. You can animate with it not only `ImageView` but any `View` and `VectorDravable`  But if You need animation on `Canvas` You should override `onDraw()` method of view with your animation like in [that](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/bouncing-a-ball-on-androids-canvas/) example.

Comment: Thank you, that looks good. You know a tutorial to see how to connect the animation parts with the gestures to start them?

Comment: When You use Android Animation You can call `start()` method for Animation Object from any gesture listener. And You also can start "canvas animation" from them (for example just add variable-flag `boolean mStartAnimation = false` in you view class and analyze it in `onDraw()` method, like this: `if (mStartAnimation) { // do animation } else { // not do animation}` and on gesture listener change it 'if (myGestureDetected) { mStartAnimation = true } ')

Comment: That sound comprehensible, thank you. But i still have no idea how to animate my canvas. I created the circle in my MainActivity, don't i animate it there as well?

Comment: Do You see [this](http://cogitolearning.co.uk/?p=1019) part of tutorial?

Comment: In general "Canvas" animation is always frame-by-frame animation, so You should draw shape in some position on first frame and redraw (delete in old position and draw on new) on new position on second frame. Whole process should not take more than 16 ms for smooth animation (16ms means 60 fps)

Comment: Okay, so in the tutorial you just mentioned the View animatedView = findViewById(R.id.animatedView); - is this my general layout or do i have to reference my canvas there? And refering to what you just said: is that a way to do it frame-by-frame?

Comment: "Do You see this part of tutorial?" is about Android Animation. Next comment - about "Canvas" animation. You can use `animatedView.startAnimation(set);` like in [this](http://cogitolearning.co.uk/?p=1019) tutorial or override `animationVew.onDraw()` to do "canvas" animation. This is two different ways.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try it out!

Comment: @AndriyOmelchenko I don't get it how i animate my Canvas like in this 'canvas tutorial' - i havent got an imageView, it just creates a circle but i don't use any kind of imageViews?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Android Animatio](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/index.html)n like in [this](http://cogitolearning.co.uk/?p=877) tutorial, or "Canvas" animation like in [that](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/bouncing-a-ball-on-androids-canvas/).